# scala - a better way to parse an array of strings into a single string

Tags: scala, function

I have implemented a method that is supposed to convert an array of strings into a single string. But getting an exception when using it with UDF and applying the UDF to a column:
val concatUdf = udf(convertArray)

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray$ofRef cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.String;
```

What should be improved in my current implementation in order to return valid String? I'm new to Scala and probably this is not the most elegant solution.

```
def convertArray: Array[String] => String =
      (strings: Array[String]) => {
        Option(strings) match {
          case Some(arr) => strings.mkString(", ")
          case Some(Array()) => ""
          case None => ""
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you could just do

```
def convertArray(strings: Array[String]): String =
  if (strings.nonEmpty)
    strings.mkString(", ")
  else
    ""
```

in your code, the second `case` is unreachable, because your first case will always match, including empty arrays. That said, your code seems to work fine for me on Scala `2.12.6` (apart from the warning about the unreachable code):

```
scala> def convertArray: Array[String] => String =
     |       (strings: Array[String]) => {
     |         Option(strings) match {
     |               case Some(arr) => strings.mkString(", ")
     |           case Some(Array()) => ""
     |           case None => ""
     |         }
     |       }
<console>:15: warning: unreachable code
                 case Some(Array()) => ""
                                       ^
convertArray: Array[String] => String

scala> convertArray(Array())
res1: String = ""

scala> convertArray(Array("bro"))
res2: String = bro

scala> convertArray(Array("bro", "dude"))
res3: String = bro, dude
```

Comment: I'm trying to apply convertArray as a udf to a Dataframe column. `val concatUdf = udf(convertArray)`. And getting the ClassCastException as above

Comment: @samba please edit your answer then, to add the relevant call. The error is not in your `convertArray` method, but in the code calling it. (You're likely not passing your method an `Array[String]`, but something else)

Comment: Yes, just solved it. I should have used Seq: `def convertArray(strings: Seq[String]): String =
  if (strings.nonEmpty)
    strings.mkString(", ")
  else
    ""` Thanks for sharing your knowledge

Answer (score 1):

Just use mkString, no need to re-invent the wheel:

```
 println(Array().mkString(", "))
 println(Array("hello").mkString(", "))
 println(Array("hello", "world").mkString(", "))
```

Output:

```
//empty string
hello
hello, world
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def convertArray(strings: Array[String]): String = Option(strings).getOrElse(Array()).mkString(", ")
```

Output :

```
scala> def convertArray(strings: Array[String]): String = Option(strings).getOrElse(Array()).mkString(", ") 
convertArray: (strings: Array[String])String

scala> convertArray(Array("to", "to", "ta", "ta")) 
res16: String = to, to, ta, ta

scala> convertArray(Array()) 
res17: String = ""

scala> convertArray(null) 
res18: String = ""
```